# How to use nested arrays in pcolumn prime ng data table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have an array in which there is another array and I'm using prime ng data table to show the data in this array, please take a look at the array structure below :

```
this.institutionalTimetable = [
{day: "Monday", entries: [{startTime: "132", endTime: "789", recess: true, subject: 'English', subjectGroup:'Maths' }, {startTime: "582", endTime: "634", recess: true, subject: 'English' , subjectGroup: 'Maths'}]},
{day: "Tuesday", entries: [{startTime: "132", endTime: "789", recess: true, subject: 'English', subjectGroup:'Maths' }, {startTime: "582", endTime: "634", recess: true, subject: 'English' , subjectGroup: 'Maths'}, {startTime: "582", endTime: "634", recess: true, subject: 'English' , subjectGroup: 'Maths'}]},
{day: "Wednesday", entries: [{startTime: "132", endTime: "789", recess: true, subject: 'English', subjectGroup:'Maths' }, {startTime: "582", endTime: "634", recess: true, subject: 'English' , subjectGroup: 'Maths'}]}

]
```

So my table structure should be like the first column should have the day value 
and from the second column based on the elements inside the entries array the columns should be repeated for all the rows

How should I repeat a `<p-column>` based on an array which is inside the main array?

Here's what I tried:

```html
<p-dataTable [value]="institutionalTimetable" class="institutetable" >
  <p-headerColumnGroup >
    <p-row>
      <p-column header="Week Days"></p-column>
      <p-column header="Time table" [colspan]="10"></p-column>
    </p-row>
  </p-headerColumnGroup>
  <p-column field="day"></p-column>
  <p-column field="entries" *ngFor="let entrys of entries">
    <ng-template let-col let-entryData="rowData" pTemplate="body">
     
      <span>{{ entrys.startTime }}</span>

    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have well understood your need.

What I would do if I were you is to recreate an array by looping on each day and each entry of *institutionalTimetable*.

Then, you would just have a simple `dataTable` like that :

```
<p-dataTable [value]="institutionalTimetable2" class="institutetable" >
  <p-headerColumnGroup >
    <p-row>
      <p-column header="Week Days"></p-column>
      <p-column header="Time table" [colspan]="5"></p-column>
    </p-row>
  </p-headerColumnGroup>
  <p-column field="day"></p-column>
  <p-column field="startTime"></p-column>
  <p-column field="endTime"></p-column>
  <p-column field="recess"></p-column>
  <p-column field="subject"></p-column>
  <p-column field="subjectGroup"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

See my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/amTrlyYjvae7CPFLbrwX?p=preview)